# Accessing process.env.BASE_URL on Google Cloud - Node.Js/Express

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform

I am working on my first Node.Js app on Google Cloud and am struggling to get the following to work when I deploy:

const baseUrl = process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'

My other process environment variable works well:
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

I haven't been able to find an example or tutorial on how to access the base url when deployed - any views on how I could get this done?

Comment: What do you expect? Would you like to have the BASE_URL populated according with your environment (Cloud Functions, Cloud RUn, App Engine)?

Comment: Thank you Guillaume. Yes thats what I am trying to accomplish. Essentially I would want to use baseUrl across my app.js and have it populate based on the URL the App Engine assigns me.

Comment: Ok, you want this automatically? Or you want to recover a BASE_URL env var manually defined?

Answer (score 1):

I have found an example [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-http#integration_tests) for BASE_URL in NodeJS. It shows the syntax.